# What is the meaning of the curvy line in $\widetilde{\sin}\theta$ and $\widetilde{\cos}\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry, notation, inner-products

I am Electrical Engineer, and iI am facing problems with solving inner space vectors. I am trying to understand it, but i can't completely understand what this curvy line represents and how it differentiates a simple sine wave from the one with a curvy line on top of it.

[image]

Here are the symbols in context:

[image]

Comment: A picture or something of the sort might help

Comment: Your question is not clear (to me). Please [edit] the question to provide a sentence or equation so we can see how this symbol is used.

Comment: There are some possibilities, like that functions are asymptotic to each other near a point. We cannot help you if you don't post a picture, an equation or an exerpt from a textbook (for example) to give the context.